# data communication over audio channel 

Tags: android, blackberry, audio, java-me

I want to send and receive data over **Audio Channel** in ***Android***,***Black Berry*** and ***J2ME***.
Is it possible ?
If Yes then How I achieve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to develop some kind of audio modem in these three OSs?

Comment: yes, I want to develop some kind of audio modem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were my decision, I would attempt to develop a [Jingle](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html)-based app.